# Container Field under Storage Account Settings is not displayed

Tags: documentation, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-edge, stream-analytics

While creating a stream analytics job for IoT Edge, one needs to associate the job with a container in a storage account. In **storage account settings** under configure section of Stream Analytics Job - Container Field is not being displayed when "Add Storage Account" is selected.

Is there a new workflow to add a storage container for a stream analytics job?

I tried adding a storage container in the storage account of the same resource group. It didn't help.

Documentation Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-stream-analytics?view=iotedge-2018-06#create-an-azure-stream-analytics-job

Issue is at Step 3, where "Container" field is not being displayed in Azure Portal - Steam Analytics Job Page

Configure IoT Edge settings - Source Documentation

1.Under Configure, select Storage account settings then select Add storage account.
2.Select the Storage account that you created at the beginning of this tutorial from the drop-down menu.
*3.For the Container field, select Create new and provide a name for the storage container.*
4.Select Save.

Image from documentation [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMOS0.png)

Answer (score 1):

The workflow does seem to have changed. Instead of specifying the container in the Portal, you only get to supply a storage account. Once you've done that, when you publish, a container will be created by ASA with your Edge Job inside of it. Future publishes will use the same container.

If you want, you can use the button at the bottom of the docs to give feedback to Microsoft so they can change the documentation.

Comment: Hi Matthijs, 

Thanks for clarifying the changes made to Azure Portal. I tried the procedure but, the Stream Analytics Job still throws a notification that "A Storage Container is required to save the job description and deploy it to IoT Edge device(s). Click here to configure your storage settings" and when routed to storage account page I get a notification that "Storage account is used to save the job configuration and compiled Stream Analytics query including all UDFs" even after specifying the resource group and storage account in the same page.
Not sure if there is a workaround

Comment: Would it be possible to update the question with two screenshots of the two notifications and the rest of the page? It worked for me yesterday, when I made a Stream Analytics job in West Europe. What region are you trying to create the job in?

Comment: Hi, I also tried on my side and can add a container to an Edge job. Screenshots will help indeed. If you have a support plan, do you mind creating a support ticket for this so our team can investigate, otherwise you can reach out to our team at AskASA @ microsoft .com . thanks,